# Div style float:left with clear not working

Tags: html, css

I have 7 divs. I am trying to make a three row three column layout. Two of the divs are different sizes. I have everything the way I want it, it's just on the third row one div jumps up to row two, and it wont budge down to row three even with clear:right.I am trying my hardest to have the design Internet Explorer 11 ready before I give up and cut off all traffic to IE.

The way the layout is rendering
[image: The way the layout is rendering]

The way it should be rendering
[image: The way it should be rendering]

````
    



<style>

[div_glimg]{ width:390px; height:390px} 
[glimg]{ float:left; background-size: cover;  }
[div_glvideo], [glvideoobject]{ width:780px; height:390px; float:left}  
</style>
<div style="background-color: white ;float:left" div_glimg>
    
 <div glim>
      <div glim1title glim1titlerez  style=" margin-top:0 !important;">Life<a> in</a> </div>
      <div glmaincdiv></div> 
      <div glimcontent>info.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

<div style="background-color: hsla(359,36%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> </div>
<div style="background-color: hsla(213,35%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> </div>

<div style="background-color: hsla(51,35%,62%,1.00); clear:left" glimgTall glimg> tall</div>    
<div style="background-color: hsla(199,35%,62%,1.00); clear:right" div_glvideo> video </div>    

    
<div style="background-color: hsla(302,35%,62%,1.00);  " div_glimg glimg> box 1</div>
<div style="background-color: hsla(302,35%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> box 2</div>




    ```
````

Comment: I would be using CSS Grid if I were you.

Comment: please show your complete code @Peter Friedlander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem :** First of all, the answer of the question, that why `clear: right;` is not working is because when the element, with `clear: right;` property is rendered, the element in the right of it has not been rendered. That is why, the right element after getting rendered is not affected.

**Solution :** Either you can choose the grid-system, or if you want to go with what you have, with fixed dimensions, you can do it like this :

```html
<style>
  [div_glimg] {
    width: 78px;
    height: 78px
  }
  
  [glimg] {
    float: left;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  [div_glvideo],
  [glimgTall] {
    float: left;
  }
  
  [div_glvideo] {
    width: 156px;
    height: 78px;
  }
  
  [glimgTall] {
    height: 156px;
    width: 78px;
  }
  [wrapper] {
    height: 234px;
    width: 234px;
  }
</style>
<div wrapper>

  <div style="background-color: white ;float:left" div_glimg>

    <div glim>
      <div glim1title glim1titlerez style=" margin-top:0 !important;">Life<a> in</a> </div>
      <div glmaincdiv></div>
      <div glimcontent>info.</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div style="background-color: hsla(359,36%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> </div>
  <div style="background-color: hsla(213,35%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> </div>

  <div style="background-color: hsla(51,35%,62%,1.00);" glimgTall glimg> tall</div>
  <div style="background-color: hsla(199,35%,62%,1.00);" div_glvideo> video </div>


  <div style="background-color: hsla(302,35%,62%,1.00);  " div_glimg glimg> box 1</div>
  <div style="background-color: hsla(302,35%,62%,1.00); " div_glimg glimg> box 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest go for grid layout for better experience. Here is example.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.item2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}
.item3{
grid-column:3;
grid-row:1;
}

.item5 {
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
.item4{
grid-row: 2 / span 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>A Five Items Grid Layout:</h1>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item item1">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item2">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item item3">3</div>  
  <div class="grid-item item4">4</div>  
  <div class="grid-item item5">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item item6">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item item7">7</div>
</div>

<p>Direct child elements(s) of the grid container automatically becomes grid items.</p>

<p>Item 1, 2, and 5 are set to span multiple columns or rows.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am making this site internet explorer safe. Grids don't play nice to cross-browser compatibility

Comment: Ok will help to solve this. @PeterFriedlander You have mention this in question what is expectation. But for that you have to give running simple snippet.

Comment: @PeterFriedlander If you are making it Internet Explorer safe, then you're not safe.

Comment: Thanks for the help,  If I was going to block all IE traffic, it would cut visitors down 10%. The only way I know is to design grids is with all Divs

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for your solution. The layout was generated using this tool: [Layoutit Grid](https://grid.layoutit.com/)

```css
html,
body,
.grid-container {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "Div-1 Div-2 Div-3" "Div-4 Div-5 Div-5" "Div-4 Div-6 Div-7";
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.Div-1 {
  grid-area: Div-1;
  background: #E975AF;
}

.Div-2 {
  grid-area: Div-2;
  background: #0075AE;
}

.Div-3 {
  grid-area: Div-3;
  background: #27408F;
}

.Div-4 {
  grid-area: Div-4;
  background: #FFF200;
}

.Div-5 {
  grid-area: Div-5;
  background: #40AD47;
}

.Div-6 {
  grid-area: Div-6;
  background: #EC008C;
}

.Div-7 {
  grid-area: Div-7;
  background: #00ADEF;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Div-1"></div>
  <div class="Div-2"></div>
  <div class="Div-3"></div>
  <div class="Div-5"></div>
  <div class="Div-6"></div>
  <div class="Div-7"></div>
  <div class="Div-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has to be corss-browser. IE doesn't work with grids.

Comment: @PeterFriedlander Then you need to tag Internet Explorer with your question. How will we know people who are still living under the rock?